# Cordova and Network access for fetching remote js/css files

Tags: cordova, networking

I am creating a simple cordova application. All my assets are local. I added a facebook endpoint for `like button`. But running via `cordova build android && cordova run android` does not show the like button.

Using `cordova serve` and localhost works and i can see the `fb-like button`.

Do i have to build a signed release apk to be able to fetch remote js/css files ?

Please find relevant information below.

Also, earlier i was loading `google-material` css assets and fonts from remote but as internet was not working, i just copied the files locally. But i donot want to do the same for fb's sdk.

Googling around, i found `android.permission.INTERNET` but it was already present in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. I added few more permissions.

I am running this on my local android device on which i have enable `usb-debugging` and `developer mode`. When app starts, it just loads and does not ask me for permission. I have not tested with release apk, as that will require signing.

Can this be the case ? How to force it to ask for permission ?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with cordova android version `6.2.3`. I am testing on `android 5.1.1 device`.

```
└─ $ ▶ cat platforms/platforms.json 
{
    "android": "6.2.3"
}ashish @ 7567 ~/work/be_autonomous/cordova (master) 
ashish @ 7567 ~/work/be_autonomous/cordova (master) 
└─ $ ▶ cordova --version
7.0.1
ashish @ 7567 ~/work/be_autonomous/cordova (master) 
└─ $ ▶ cat config.xml 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.beautonomous.first" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>BeAutonomous</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
</widget>
ashish @ 7567 ~/work/be_autonomous/cordova (master) 
└─ $ ▶ cat 
BeAutonomous.apk   hooks/             .npmignore         package-lock.json  plugins/           run_emulator.sh    run_studio.sh      www_org/           
config.xml         node_modules/      package.json       platforms/         res/               run.sh             www/               
ashish @ 7567 ~/work/be_autonomous/cordova (master) 
└─ $ ▶ cat platforms/android/
android.json         assets/              build.gradle         CordovaLib/          gradle/              gradlew              libs/                project.properties   settings.gradle      wrapper.gradle
AndroidManifest.xml  build/               cordova/             .gitignore           .gradle/             gradlew.bat          platform_www/        res/                 src/                 
ashish @ 7567 ~/work/be_autonomous/cordova (master) 
└─ $ ▶ cat platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.beautonomous.first" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
</manifest>
ashish @ 7567 ~/work/be_autonomous/cordova (master) 
└─ $ ▶
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook sdk has url that starts from `//facebo...`.
In Android, it resovles to `file://facebo..`

So, loading of facebook sdk fails.

To find the bug, i had to debug the app in chrome console.
If you can deploy app locally to device over `usb debugging`, then open `chrome` and type `chrome://inspeect/#devices` and error was written in console.

However, even after the fix of adding `https://facebo..`, its not visible. The reason is that facebook creates an iframe, which is not visible in cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can fetch remote css and js file. I did it before. The most important things that "cordova.js" and  "document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);"  must be in your local assest. You can put other files 
on your server and call them from there.

Secondly, You must have internet permission, and access origin rights. I can see that your config.xml has this options so you did this.